# json_encode doesn't generate the JSON form I need

Tags: php, json

I cant get valid response for my jquery script.

my response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "attack": null,
        "shield": null,
        "speed": null,
        "cargo": null,
        "upg_slots": "1"
    }
}
```

code:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => true,
    'data' => array(
        'attack' => null,
        'shield' => null,
        'speed' => null,
        'cargo' => null,
        'upg_slots' => "1"
    )
));
```

valid response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "attack": null,
            "shield": null,
            "speed": null,
            "cargo": null,
            "upg_slots": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I knew JSON was powerful, but "god form"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a list with a single dictionary in it, you need to nest your keyword array within a positional array:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'attack' => null,
        'shield' => null,
        'speed' => null,
        'cargo' => null,
        'upg_slots' => "1"
    )
);
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'data' => $data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing one more array under the `'data'` key in your response, just wrap it again like this:

```
 echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'data' => array(array( 'attack' => null, 'shield' => null, 'speed' => null, 'cargo' => null, 'upg_slots' => "1"))));
//                                                    ^^^
```